# How do I change the background color of the container using onClick?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using Next.js. I have a set of colors in a different file. How do I change the background color randomly when clicking the button?

The `Color.js` file

```
export const Colors = [
    "#16a085",
    "#27ae60",
    "#2c3e50",
    "#f39c12",
    "#e74c3c",
    "#9b59b6",
    "#FB6964",
    "#342224",
    "#472E32",
    "#BDBB99",
    "#77B1A9",
    "#73A857",
];
```

The Main file

```
import { Colors } from "./Colors.js";

export default function Home() {
    const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
    const [color, setColor] = useState(Colors);
    console.log(color);
    const changeColor = () => {       
         setColor(color[randomColor]);   
    };
```

The Error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '9')
```

Comment: can you show us the JSX?

Comment: I think you can already replace the ```12``` by ```Colors.length - 1```

Comment: I did something that's working awaiting you to show us more code : https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-cori-l9pj7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made 3 mistakes in your code.

First you have created `color` state with whole color array that you have imported.

But instead use one default or empty value as below

```
const [color, setColor] = React.useState("#16a085");
```

The next mistake is to you are fetching index from the state `color` which is not an array once you click on the button it becomes a string and it will index out of bound as no color string has length greater than 7

It can be fixed by

```
setColor(Colors[randomColor]);
```

Now you will get rid of the error but the color won't change because your random number generator is outside and it is generate when the component updates so fix will be to place it inside the function.

The final code I guess will look as below

```
import { Colors } from "./Colors";

export default function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState("#16a085");
  const changeColor = () => {
    const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
    setColor(Colors[randomColor]);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ color: color }}>hello</div>
      <button onClick={changeColor}>change</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```